# Hackerrank Challenge- The Hurdle Race. What I am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

so I am working on a HarckerRank Challenge called "The Hurdle Race". I have two ways I completed the challenge in my IDE but it only passes two test cases when I put it in the IDE in HackerRank. When I take one of the case tests and put it in my own IDE I get the correct result. Am I missing something? Is my code incorrect? Below are my codes.
[image]

```js
// 1st:
function hurdleRace(k, height) {
  let maxH = Math.max.apply(null, k);
  let iGotTheHops = 0;
  console.log(maxH);

  if (height < maxH) {
    console.log(maxH - height);
    return maxH - height;
  } else {
    console.log(0);
    return iGotTheHops;
  }
}

// 2nd:
function hurdleRace2(k, height) {
  // Write your code here

  let maxHight = k[0];
  let iGotHops = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    if (k[i] > maxHight) {
      maxHight = k[i];
    }
  }

  if (height < maxHight) {
    console.log(maxHight - height);
    return maxHight - height;

  } else {
    console.log(iGotHops);
    return iGotHops;
  }
}

hurdleRace([1,6,3,5,2],4)
hurdleRace2([1,6,3,5,2],4)
```

This is the test it flags as incorrect. States that my return is 0.

Comment: Are you sure the parameters to your functions are correct? Do you work on the input as is described in the prompt? Perhaps your variables are reversed and you are just returning 0 in the live version as a result.

Comment: @skyline3000, You are correct.... I am so blind for not realizing I had the parameters switched! Thank you.